# how to edit highlight text in vim after searching

Tags: vim

I like to use "*" to search text in vim. after hight light the target text, I want to edit all of them, is there any way I can do it in vim? for example, after highlight text, I just need to press ctrl+i then the highlight text can be edited simultaneously

Comment: do you want find and replace ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simultaneous editing (like seen in other editors) is not built into Vim (but there are plugins). You don't need them, though. After `*`, the text is stored in the *last search pattern* register, and you can just `:substitute//` without repeating what you're searching for:

```
:%s//replacement/g
```

The `%` is a *range* and applies this to the whole buffer; the `/g` is a *flag* that replaces all (globally) instances, not just the first in each line. Read `:help :s` for details.

Answer (score 2):

As a nice alternative. You can use `gn` and the `.` command.

- Set your search pattern i.e. `*` or `/foo`
- Change your highlighted pattern via `c` operator over the `gn` motion
- `cgnbar<esc>` will change the highlighted area to `bar`.
- Now you can use `.` too repeat this change. You can also use `n` to skip places.

Note: This requires at least 7.4

For more help see:

```
:h gn
:h .
```

Comment: This is should be the answer. Thanks for this Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin.

Personally, I like @Ingo's solution. The less plugins the better.

Comment: Plugins are OK, the more, the better. VimL plugins (portability). Neobundle as a manager, as it has epic lazy loading.

Comment: The more plugins the better? Something tells me that was for shock value. It's not a loading problem; I just find vim defaults to be useful tools when used as intended. Plugins tend to confuse, need to be managed and updated, require extra learning, etc.

Comment: Well. With enough plugins you do get to loading times of epic proportions.

Comment: @Conner, I tend to customize my all every day systems. Its not confusing to me at all, I don't need to manage them much or manually update them with Neobundle. I can lock revisions I like and that is it for eternity. What do you think that Ingo Karkat developed hundreed plugins for shock value ? Extra learning is never a problem. Small price to pay for being faster on the long run.

Comment: @progo, Not necessarily. I use `NeoBundleLazy` almost exclusively. Plugins are loaded just as I need them. My load time with 100++ plugins is around 1s.

Comment: @majkinetor I'm glad you're happy with how you run your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to edit the word with another you can use the `substitute` command. (e.g. `:%s/hi/hello/g`)

This will change all occurrences of `hi` to `hello` in the file.

Comment: I think he wants to replace different words not just hello

Comment: if that is the case then
    :%s/\<foo\>/bar/gc
Change only whole words exactly matching 'foo' to 'bar'; ask for confirmation.